# Post NSNotification when HTML page loads

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova

I am very new to Objective C and I am using phonegap to create an app. Is there a way to send NSNotifications onDeviceReady or when a function is executed?

Comment: Yes you can send notification from anywhere, anytime.

If you wish to send a notification simply post the notification as the last statement of the method.

Comment: in obj-c I can do it like I commented above, but no idea in js

Comment: So I want to send a notification when onDeviceReady function is executed how do i do that please?

I have tried adding something like this

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(deviceReady:) name: @"onDeviceReady" object: nil];
return YES;
}

- (void)deviceReady:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSLOG(@"HEY");
}`

Javascript Function:

`function onDeviceReady() {
          console.log('Device is Ready');
        }`

Comment: looks ok, this should work

Comment: The console is logging Device is Ready but "HEY" isn't being logged in console :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in way to do what you want

Cordova is posting a notification when the page is loaded, not sure if this is called just when the cordovaready or a few moments before that

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPageDidLoadNotification object:self.webView]];
```

you can get it like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pageDidLoad) name:CDVPageDidLoadNotification object:self.webView];
```

but if you want the deviceReady, you'll need to create your own plugin that post that notification. To create a plugin follow this guide http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide